# Got too many opened files error in db console

Tags: mongodb, go

I am working on a Golang project and for db server I am using MongoDB. It was working fine but today morning I got the issue "Too many opened files..." and MongoDB server shut down automatically. Now MongoDB server crashed after every 15-20 min with the same message. I have searched for the solution and set the opened files limit as

```
* hard nofile 990000
* soft nofile 990000
root hard nofile 990000
root soft nofile 990000
```

But I am still getting the same issue "Too many opened files" after restart the service.
Please let me know how I can fix this.

Comment: @mkopriva already checked this. We are closing the files.

Comment: How should we know without your code?